# Context menu disappears if PySide app is running from IPython interactive console

Tags: python, contextmenu, pyqt4, ipython, pyside

In the minimal example given below, the context menu (right click on white section of the gui) is displayed only briefly and then disappears. This is the case if the app is started from the IPython (0.13.1) console. When started normally from shell it works as it should.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from IPython.lib.guisupport import get_app_qt4, start_event_loop_qt4

class ContextTestGui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_ContextTestWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.treeView.addAction(self.ui.actionCopy)
        self.ui.treeView.addAction(self.ui.actionShow)

class Ui_ContextTestWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, ContextTestWindow):
        ContextTestWindow.resize(200, 100)
        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(ContextTestWindow)
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        self.treeView.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))

        self.actionCopy = QtGui.QAction("Copy",ContextTestWindow)
        self.actionShow = QtGui.QAction("Show",ContextTestWindow)

def create_window(window_class,**kwargs):
    app = get_app_qt4(sys.argv)
    window = window_class()
    window.show()
    start_event_loop_qt4(app)
    return window

if __name__ == '__main__':
    simgui = create_window(ContextTestGui)
```

Comment: I believe this is Issue [#2380](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2380), which purports to be fixed in current git master.  Can you check?

Comment: Yes it is, although those problematic dialogs (save, open) mentioned in the issue work as expected only context menu is defective. When diff in commit [66c77ff392](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/66c77ff392ad7425f8443e1343f5bf8c84a7b5d7) referenced in issue #2380 is applied, i.e. application is replaced with event loop, problem is gone. Now I wonder what to     do in my app except to wait for 0.14?

Comment: Depending on your deployment situation, you can either apply the patch directly to your IPython, or have your app monkeypatch IPython on load.  What you would need to override is `IPython.lib.inputhook.enable_qt4` with a version that points to your own function (aka from IPython master) that performs the right action.

Comment: Thank you, this other approach should be more appropriate for my situation. Could you make an answer from your comments so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, I'll type it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is IPython Issue [#2380](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2380), which should be fixed in current git master.

If you want your app to workaround this bug in 0.13, you will have to ship with your own code a version of IPython/lib/inputhookqt4.py from master, and monkeypatch IPython with:

```
from IPython.lib import inputhook
inputhook.enable_qt4 = my_enable_qt4
```

OR, alternatively, just override create_inputhook_qt4

```
from IPython.lib import inputhookqt4
inputhookqt4.create_inputhook_qt4 = my_create_inputhook_qt4
```

I expect both approaches should work, as long as you do it before `%gui qt` is called.

Answer (score 1):

How do you run the application ? `In[1]: %run file.py`?

I can't reproduce it on ~last master (feb 4 f46bfec 08389b4) with OS X